# PHP 7.3 PDO Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, authentication

I want to give a user an error if they log in with wrong email and password,
the email part i get it but the password keep giving me this error, am using php 7.3 pdo with sql server

```
 public function login($email, $password, $remember){
      $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
      $this->db->bind('email', $email);

      $row = $this->db->single();

      $password_hash = $row->password;

      if(password_verify($password, $password_hash)) {

        if($remember){
          setcookie('email', $email, time() + 86400);
        }

        return $row;
      }else{
        return false;
      }

    }
```

Comment: it stacks at this line $password_hash = $row->password; if the password and email are incorrect

Comment: Which line is giving you the error?

Comment: This one $password_hash = $row->password;

Answer (score 0):

You can use an inline expression to assign `$row` and ensure that the data exists for that query by using `isset()`.

```
public function login($email, $password, $remember)  {

    $this->db->query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email');
    $this->db->bind('email', $email);

    if(isset(($row = $this->db->single()))) {
        $password_hash = $row->password;
        // Your logic
    } else {
        // Email did not exist
    }

}
```

If the email does not exist, `$row` will return empty. **P.S** I'd stay away from selecting `*` in your queries in future, only select what you need.

Alternatively, you probably want to ensure to `LIMIT` 1.

```
public function login($email, $password, $remember = false) {

    // If $this->db is a PDO instance
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->execute(array($email));

    if(isset(($row = $stmt->fetch()))) {
        // Your logic
    } else {
        // Bad email
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping @jaquarh